# Android app for offline podcasts

Tags: offline, podcast, android-app

I've got some archives of podcasts that I want to listen to on my Android phone. They are MP3s.

Standard music player apps aren't any good for this, because the app needs to save and resume playback position, even after a full restart.

I looked at some audiobook playback apps and tried [Sirin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sirin.android&hl=en&gl=US), and it does the saving of playback position, but it tries really hard too organise the different episodes as if they're book chapters, which ends up being messy.

Other features that would be nice are:

- Automatically scanning a folder for new episodes
- Grouping episodes using MP3 metadata like title and date
- Maybe keeping playback history even after files have been deleted

Can anyone suggest a good app for this?

Comment: This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/252786/131553) may be relevant

Comment: If you organized your episodes into directories and alpha-numerical, a [Folderplay](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay#group_335) app might help. Otherwise, one of the [Podcast](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_network#group_1165) players could support offline mode. I don't listen to podcasts frequently myself, so I cannot give a clear recommendation here. Disclosure: the links go to my own Android website.